# Illustrator create border like effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon

I am using Illustrator. I got this:

[image]

and I want to create this effect:

[image]

At the moment I am using a white border to create this effect but I want to remove the part from the outer lines. I know that this is possible but how?

Comment: It took me a second to realize this checkmark wasn't a like a line going across the eye signifying that it something is perhaps hidden or something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an outer stroke to the central shape

[image]

- Go to menu Object → Expand
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +
  <kbd>8</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +
  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> Win to **Release the Compound Shape**
- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> Win to **Ungroup**
- Select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to activate the **Shape Builder Tool** and click in every part of the outer stroke holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete

[image]

- Delete the leftover shapes

[image]

Comment: I can't use Expand?!? I can only use Expand Appearance. I used this instead and then I used Expand but then nothing happens. I made this check symbol with two lines which I expanded and then put together using pathfinder. What am I doing wrong?!?

Comment: After expanding appearance you can't follow the other steps?

Comment: Yes I can't. When I expand the appearance "Expand" isn't muted anymore but when I click on it nothing happens. Normally a box would appear where I can select some options and then expand the object but now nothing comes.

Comment: Did you add the stroke to the shape?

Comment: Yes I do. Strangely when I expand the appearance it looks like it added two strokes... Here's an image: https://pasteboard.co/IkME1dY.png.

Comment: That's because the fill and the stroke are expanded. Just follow the next steps: release comp. shape, ungroup, etc...

Comment: Ok it works now. Idk what I made wrong but I still had to expand the eye. Thanks for your help! I would vote your answer up but I don't have enough reputation. Sorry.

Comment: Glad to help...